# Value of ResultSet when the SQL statement is a wrong syntax?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using mySQL. As you see, the SQL statement is wrong at `SELECT`. So, I wonder what value the `rs` is?
I hope to get some advice. I thank you so much;

```
String sql = "SELCT * FROM user WHERE username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should use `PreparedStatement` instead of **injecting** SQL into the query.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no value because [`Statement.executeQuery(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) would throw a [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html). As the linked Javadoc says,

> Returns:
>   a `ResultSet` object that contains the data produced by the given query; never `null`
>
> Throws:
>   [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed `Statement`, the given SQL statement produces anything other than a single `ResultSet` object, the method is called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`

Answer (score 0):

It will return you an exception having message like syntax error.

Comment: It will **throw** an exception, not return an exception.

Comment: I am also saying in same sense but thank you for mentioning.

Comment: Returning and throwing are fundamentally different things in Java. It helps to be precise to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to find is to debug your code by putting break points in code & examining / watching values of variables . Most IDEs have these debugging features. In addition to Elliott Frisch's answer, if I restructure your code like below then in case of invalid / incorrect SQL, control comes to `catch` block and you can see that value of `rs` remains `null`.

```
public void executeQuery(Connection conn, String username,String password) {
    String sql = "SELCT * FROM user WHERE username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stm = null;
    try {
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        rs= stm.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()) {
         //Extract ResultSet here as per needed logic 
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     // Your control comes here if query is wrong , put a break point at below line & examine value of rs
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        // Close resources not needed after this method call like - result sets , statements & connection  
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly statement won't execute, so next execution is depends on how you are going to handle that exception. So, if exception comes and if you handle also there will be null in ResultSet because no value assigned to it.